# How do i display the line only once while the timer is keep working?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AnimateCheckBoxes();
}

private void AnimateCheckBoxes()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ScrollLabel._lines.Length; i++)
    {
        if (ScrollLabel._lines[i].Contains("Test"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ScrollLabel._lines[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

I want that the MessageBox.Show will be display only once without stop the timer how can i do it ?

If more then one line is containing the string Test how can i display both lines ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use an `instance boolean` variable

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                AnimateCheckBoxes();
            }
     private static bool  displayed  ;  
            private void AnimateCheckBoxes()
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < ScrollLabel._lines.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (ScrollLabel._lines[i].Contains("Test")&&!displayed)
                    {
                        displayed  = true; 
                        MessageBox.Show(ScrollLabel._lines[i]);

                    }

                }
            }
```

Comment: Its kkeping show me the messagebox.show many times all the time a new window of the messagebox.

Comment: Ah since its messagebox.show i need to click on the OK if not its never get to the true.

Comment: @user3200169 just interchange the lines then. First `displayed = true` and then `MessageBox.Show(...)`